# Questions regarding Camera2 class in Android Studio and API level to develop Flashlight App

Tags: android-studio, flashlight

I'm just starting to study Android Studio.

Trying to practice by creating custom flashlight application, but am having hard time doing so. There were many related questions here on S.O that I thought would be a perfect to take it as example. But those questions were asked few years ago and Its not working for me.

My problem is that when I try to use Camera object, Android Studio tells me that the class is deprecated, and that it should use camera2 class.
In the Android Studio website, it says to use CameraManager to work with camera. However, when I try to do it, it says "call requires API level 23 (current Min is 22).... " I'm testing the app with my phone which is a Galaxy S5, and in the options tab to choose the device or emulator. It shows my phone device is at API level 22.
Well. I'd think then that my phone is too old. But I have downloaded different FlshLight apps from Google Play store and my phone is able to run it just fine. Could anyone guide me to the right direction?

Here is my code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mButton);

}

// When user press the button, turn the Flashlight On.
public void buttonPressed(View view){
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String [] list = manager.getCameraIdList();
            for(int i =  0; i < list.length; i ++){
                 manager.setTorchMode(list[i],true);
            }


    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.johnlee.myflash" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if statement that check if the os version is below or above API level 23, and then use the appropriate camera.

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.THE_REQUIRE_VERSION) {
        // only for a specific and newer versions
    }
    else{
        //for deprecated versions
    }
```